# How to Override Forgot Password Message, in Magento

Tags: validation, magento, email-validation, forgot-password

I want to Override the Forgot Password Message of Magento in Frontend sites:

1. When I click Forgot Password in my frontend site, It says:

If there is an account associated with loremipsum@yahoo.com you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.

**I want to override this message with an email validation of:**

1. Your email address loremipsum@yahoo.com does not exist, or
2. We've sent you a reset link in your email address loremipsum@yahoo.com

Do I have an alternative solutions in Magento Default Message with validation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find this in

```
Mage_Customer_AccountController
```

and go to the function `forgotPasswordPostAction()`

**and replace with this code** **

*your condition start with //custom code start***

```
 public function forgotPasswordPostAction()
        {

        $email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        if ($email) {
            if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                $this->_getSession()->setForgottenEmail($email);
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Invalid email address.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
                return;
            }

            /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                ->loadByEmail($email);

            if ($customer->getId()) {
                try {
                    $newResetPasswordLinkToken = Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
                    $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
                    $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
                } catch (Exception $exception) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError($exception->getMessage());
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
                    return;
                }
            }
            else //custom code start
            {
              $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Your email address %s does not exist.',Mage::helper('customer')->htmlEscape($email)));
             $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;  
            }//custom code end
            $this->_getSession()
                ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customer')->__('We have sent you a reset link in your email address %s .', Mage::helper('customer')->htmlEscape($email)));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please enter your email.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
            return;
        }
    }
```

**after that you can override this**

Comment: Ok. Thanks, wait. I'll check on it. :)

Comment: Many Thanks! That's a big Help. The code is now working. Marked it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Go to following class

```
Mage_Customer_AccountController
```

and inside this function this message exist

```
 forgotPasswordPostAction()
```

you can OVERRIDE this function from above class

Comment: Thanks, So how do I pull email address from magento. Kindly Check the code. Thanks,

Comment: this variable $email contains the email-id, u can use it

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I'll check on it! :)